# How to build an exception that points to a saved python traceback?

Tags: python, exception, stack-trace, traceback

I'm trying to do something a little weird. I want to save a stack trace in Python, and then when I throw an exception on some later line, I want that exception to have the stack trace that I saved earlier, rather than the default traceback. I'm trying to give the illusion that an error was thrown from a different line than it actually was thrown from.

To make this a bit more concrete, I'd like to be able to do something like

```
class Pipeline:
    
    def __init__(self):
        saved_traceback = None

    def m1(self):
        # ... Do some work ....
        saved_traceback = save_traceback()
    
    def execute(self):
        try:
           # .... Do Some work 
        except Exception as e:
           raise SpecialError(saved_traceback)
```

And then I'd run a script like:

```
foo = Pipeline()
foo.m1()
foo.execute()
```

And I want to implement `execute` in such a way that if an error is raised in its execution, the traceback instead points to the call to `m1`. This is part of a sort of lazy pipeline building domain specific language where no work happens until you call `execute`, so all error messages would come from `execute`. Instead, I want users to see an error that points to the method that added the faulty pipeline step.

Comment: seems like an interesting problem, you mind adding a code sample to explain what you want?

Comment: Yes, added an example to clarify.

Comment: So, if you do `1/0` in `ml` and that gets you `ZeroDivisionError` and let's say you get `AttributeError` in `execute` - you want to raise `ZeroDivisionError` there?

It still feels a bit fuzzy btw!

Comment: Not exactly. I won't get any error in `m1`, I just want to be able to make it look like `m1` was the source of whatever error was thrown during `execute`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `traceback.format_exc()` to save the traceback as a string.

```
import traceback

try:
    print(a)
except:
    traceback_str = traceback.format_exc()
```

`print(a)` will fail with `NameError` because `a` was never defined. In the `except` block, the most recent traceback will be saved to `traceback_str` as a string.

Comment: So this is doable (and there are ways to do this that don't require throwing an exception at all the way you did here). But what I was trying to do was to change the real python traceback entirely, replacing it with the saved one.

Comment: So in the print(a) example, you want to raise a saved traceback instead of a NameError?